# Position of draggables in droppable

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I would like to moves draggables to a droppable.
The problem is that they have to be "arranged" nicely after a draggable was dropped. 
For a first step I wanted to tell that the left position of a draggable is always 20px.

I have the drop event:

```
...( {
   drop: function (event, ui) {
       alert(ui.position.left);
       ...
```

This shows me the left position of the draggable.
But I'm not able to change it with

```
ui.position.left = 20;
```

I've read here that position is calculated with the offset and those are readonly variables.
How am I able to set the left position?
Or is there any easier way? Any tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

You could append the dragged item to the droppable container like this :

```
$('#dropContanier').droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).append(ui.draggable); 
    }
});
```

In that case, the element will be arranged according to your CSS styles

Comment: not in any useful way for me - I can't get my images to show up where I drop them

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those are read-only variables - offset and position are values of the user interface, not attributes of your elements. You need to use ui.draggable's css "top" and "left".